# Interact/manipulate Values of Application through the new C# Interactive Console

Tags: c#, console, visual-studio-2015, interactive

Good Day, 
i just found out about the existence of the "C# Interactive Console" while playing around with VS2015. The basic functions and operations are well documented.
I am woundering if there is a way to start a application in Debug-Mode an to interact / manipulate Values of the application by using the "C# Interactive Console". By now i was using IronPython/DLR, which has the backdraw of having to provide Wrapper/Facade logic for each desired interaction scenario.

edit: To be more precise about the intention of this question, the idea is to have a way to manipulate object values at Runtime not having to uses static classes and/or breakpoints. Like a REPL console window for accessing the internas of an running application. By now i use IronPython and wrapper classes, wich requires creating wrapper classes for accessing items. 
/edit:

Thanks to you colleagues out there!

Uli

Answer (score 0):

If you want to alter the state of an application while it's running in debug you would want to enter your command into the immediate window, not C# interactive.

Comment: Hello Jonathon, thank you for your quick reply. The reason for asking about  C# interactive was because of the option of bringing in scripts, which allows more use cases of automated testing to be covered. Would the immediate window allow the use of scripts/predefined procedures too?